# Pictureupload + Cropping - Best practice for the User

Tags: usability

Having a Dating-Website the user can upload some pictures.

We struggle a little with defining the best strategy how the user can handle his pictures.

The first (ever) uploaded Picture is his Profilepicture. That makes sense i guess.

Now we have different approaches.

---

**The user uploads another picture**

1. This picture automatically becomes the Profilepicture (and the cropper is popping up (see #2)
2. its is just antother Picture. If the user wants this as his Profilepicture, he needs to click "make this to profile"

---

**Cropping Pictures**

Here we struggle badly and we can't unify our ideas.

1. The User is clicking on "make this as profile picture", the cropper is popping up, the user is cropping his picture as he wants to, and then a **new picture** (the cropped one) is added to the pictures. **cropping only works if the user wants a picture as a profile picture**
2. the user can crop **any** picture and the picture will be **replaced** by the cropped one.

---

So can somebody help us, which approaches are the better ones? Or are there any other usefull approaches, how to deal with pictures?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but as far as best user experience, I like how sites like behance work...

1) go to your profile

2) edit your profile

3) edit your profile image

4) pick an image (this method differs on desktop and mobile - mobile brings up your library of images whereas desktop gives you the standard open file dialog). you could also allow picking from already uploaded images, but you shouldn't force the user to choose from there because that's frustrating.

5) crop image

6) save image, profile image is replaced

as for other images, I think that should be a separate action. perhaps one that says "add pictures" or something.  the process may run similarly to upload profile process, but generally you wouldn't run a cropper on uploaded photos unless they have to have a thumbnail image generated or something (IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

You need to focus on proper **Onboarding**.

If a person is signing up for your Dating service, the **first** most important step will be to get his profile set up.

Have a step by step procedure from Name, Profile-Picture, Description, More photos etc.

On the **Profile Picture** page, you could mention this:

> *To get the girls attracted, you'll need personality, charisma and empathy, but first, a **Profile Picture**!*

On uploading the picture, if it's of the correct size:

> *Wow! Looking good, bud! Let's move on to the next section!*

If it needs to be cropped:

> *That's too big for her. Crop your photo below to match the **150X150** size.*

Get creative with innuendos if you're making a dating website.

You can go later to add other photos in his profile. But the primary one to be uploaded MUST be the Profile picture. Definitely with a skip option, but this will lead to low quality users on your website if people tend to skip uploading their picture. Also, what's wrong with having their Facebook/Instagram photo as their Profile photo for the start?

Comment: Although I don't think your answer is really about he question at hand, I like your answer in general, very good tips. However, your last part *what's wrong with having their Facebook/Instagram photo as their Profile photo for the start?* is a big no-no, dating site users needs to know their privacy is secured, and by adding profile photos from other services anyone with some knowledge can do an image search of Facebook profiles and match it with dating sites profiles. In short: please never do this!

Comment: Tinder uses Facebook photos. My point is, if they ask to upload or skip profile picture, you get to have a lot of dead users at hand, which might be the reason for dwindling of users later on. My answer is a solution to not run into the problems the OP might have in the first place.

Comment: But yes, depends on the type of Dating site. For something like Ashley Madison, one could never trust connecting Fb or Twitter. Something fun like Tinder, well, yes, why not. All depends on what kind of site the OP is aiming for but thanks for the correction.

Comment: its a dating in souteastasia, so everybody is a "social-media whore". as the foreigners (the customers) are coming alone, we need to focus on attracting the girls for the site. wherever the girls are, the boys are coming.

Comment: so the question was more about the approach how to get the profile picture. should the user explicit say "i want to upload a profile picture" or should he just be able to choose out of his already uploaded pictures"

Comment: He should be able to select any of his earlier uploaded pictures as his profile picture. If some other photo is selected already as the Profile Picture, you'll need an indicator to specify that.

Comment: but for then: if he can select any previous pictures as a profile picture, does he needs to crop those or just click "make this profile" and its done ?

also: can a user crop any picture at any given time? should the picture be replaced with the cropped one or should a croped-out copy be created?

Comment: If the picture doesn't fit your specific resolution, then yes, it'll automatically open the crop tool and ask them to crop it. And no, the picture won't be replaced, a cropped copy will be created which will be hidden from all images but will only be used in the profile.